# Factors of Direct Composite of Subsemigroups are in fact Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, semigroups, direct-product

Seth Warner's "Modern Algebra" (1965), exercise 13.6.

Context: self-study, from a many-years-ago maths degree which did not focus deeply on abstract algebra.

> If a group $G$ is the direct composite of subsemigroups $H$ and $K$, then $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$.

The object of this exercise is to demonstrate that even though the factor structures are as general as being **semigroups**, the nature of the direct composite (also known as "internal direct product") constrains those factors to actually being **normal subgroups**.

Now, the definition given for **direct composite** is as follows (paraphrased for convenience):

> Let $H$ and $K$ be closed subsets of an algebraic structure $(G, \odot)$. Then $(G, \odot)$ is the **direct composite** of $H$ and $K$ iff the mapping $\phi: H \times K \to G$ defined as $$\phi: (x, y) \to x \odot y$$ is an isomorphism from the cartesian product of $(H, \odot_H)$ and $(K, \odot_K)$.

Now for the purpose of this exercise, I understand that this is *all* we are allowed to use, that is, we are not given that $(a, b) \odot (c, d) = (a \odot c, b \odot d)$. This is being glossed over in the text book, and taken for granted.

It is straightforward to show that every element of $G$ is of the form $h \odot k$ for some $h \in H$, $k \in K$. This follows directly from the fact that $\phi$ is surjective.

Similarly, it is also easy to show that $H \cap K = e$ (where $e$ is the identity element of $G$) follows from the fact that $\phi$ is injective.

It still remains to prove that both $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, which will be done by proving that the identity $e$ is the identity of both $H$ and $K$ (not sure what to use to get that to follow), and then that each element of $H$ and $K$ has an inverse in that set, which I haven't even begun to think about.

Once I've got that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups, it is straightforward to prove normality, because I can just copy that bit from a textbook. :-)

In summary, I think I need to show that:

- $(a, b) \odot (c, d) = (a \odot c, b \odot d)$
- Both $H$ and $K$ are groups (from which it will follow that they are normal subgroups of $G$)

unless there is a way to get where I want to go without achieving the above.

Any suggestions as to where to start -- given the constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part use that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, hence in particular an injective group homomorphism. The crucial observation is the following:

$$
\phi((a,b)\odot(c,d))
=\phi((a,b))\odot\phi((c,d))
=(a\odot b)\odot(c\odot d)
=\phi((a\odot b,c\odot d))
$$

As $a,b,c,d$ were arbitrary we just proved that the group structure on the cartesian product is the natural one.

For the second part start with noting that if $h\in H$, then $h=h\odot 1_G$ is the unique representation of $h\in H\subseteq G$. This just follows using that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and elements in the product $H\times K$ are equal iff their coordinates coincide. Now write $h^{-1}\in G$ as $h^{-1}=h'\odot k'$. Lift the equalities

$$
h\odot h^{-1}
=(h\odot 1_G)\odot(h'\odot k')
=1_G
=h^{-1}\odot
=(h'\odot k')\odot(h\odot 1_G)
$$

to $H\times K$ along $\phi$. By the above we then get that

$$
(h,1_G)\odot(h',k')
=(hh',k')
=(1_G,1_G)
=(h'h,k')
=(h',k')\odot(h,1_G)
$$

which is only possible if $h'=h^{-1}$ and $k'=1_G$. This shows that $H$ is a subgroup and the argument is identical for $K$.

However, this is a *very* unusual way of approaching direct products.

---

**EDIT:** There is a very important point to remark on: $H\times K$ is a group with respect to *some* operation; otherwise it is not meaningful to talk about isomorphisms (or even homomorphisms for that matter) unless you are using this word in a non-standard way.

So the statement "$\phi\colon H\times K\to G$ is an isomorphism" includes the assertion that $H\times K$ is a group and that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Although I admit that writing $\odot$ for the operation on $H\times K$ was not the best choice of notation.

Maybe to make it clearer: Suppose that $\phi\colon(H\times K,\odot_{H\times K})\to(G,\odot_G)$ is an isomorphism of groups, then:

\begin{align*}
\phi((a,b)\odot_{H\times K}(c,d))
&=\phi((a,b))\odot_G\phi((c,d))
\\
&=(a\odot_G b)\odot_G(c\odot_G d)
\\
&=\phi((a\odot_G b,c\odot_G d))
\end{align*}

We know that both entries are still in their respective substructures as those are closed (under composition I assume) by assumption. So this is a valid equation implying that the composition law $\odot_{H\times K}$ such that $\phi$ is an isomorphism is necessarily just given by componentwise compostion using $\odot_G$, i.e.

$$
(a,b)\odot_{H\times K}(c,d)=(a\odot_G b,c\odot_G d)\,.
$$

Comment: Yes it *is* unusual -- but then this is a work on abstract algebra in general, and is not dedicated to group theory. He is attempting to take a step back from the approach where the atomic structure is a group, and beginning from the most general algebraic structures possible and finding out what the common properties are first, *then* focusing down onto the specific cases where there is an identity and all elements have an inverse. No other works I've seen tread the same path - but then as has been pointed out many times, I'm not reading the Correct Books.

Comment: Incidentally, please allow that I am evaluating this post gradually, hence while I have upvoted it, I have not accepted it as an answer until I have had the time to study it thoroughly, and to do that I need to wait till I am not distracted by day-job concerns. :-)

Comment: @PrimeMover It's *even* unusual for a book on abstract algebra. Anyway, I see where the book might be coming from and it's an interesting take, although, IMO, unnecessarily complicating things. If anything remains unclear I'm happy to expand to my answer!

Comment: I am building up my understanding of the Internal Direct Product Theorem, and all is becoming more clear as I progress. I studied all this many years ago, but it is only now, when I am trying to generate a comprehensive set of teaching notes on the subject, that I am taking the time to really comprehend what it's all about.

Comment: There is still one point I don't get. I see $\phi((a,b)\odot(c,d)) = \phi((a,b)) \odot \phi ((c,d))$, but at this stage $(a,b)\odot(c,d)$ is still not defined. $(a,b)$ is an ordered pair of elements of $S$. $\odot$ is an operation on elements of $S$, not on ordered pairs of elements of $S$. It seems as though a tacit assumption is being made to *define* (a,b) \odot (c,d)$ as "being" $(a \odot b),(c \odot d)$ ...

Comment: ... or is it that, having defined $\phi$ as being a homomorphism, it is *this* which leads on to $\phi ((a,b)) \odot \phi((c,d))$ being equal to $\phi ((a,b)\odot(c,d))$? It more naturally seems to me that it should be $\phi(\phi(a,b),\phi(c,d))$, as (looking more closely) even $\phi ((a,b)\odot(c,d))$ is not "properly" defined as we haven't even established that $(a,b)\odot(c,d)$ is itself an ordered pair, if we have not made that "tacit assumption" up there that $(a,b)\odot(c,d)$ is *defined* as $(a\odot b,c\odot d)$

Comment: In the above I think I mean $(a,b)\odot(c,d)$ is defined as $(a \odot c, b \odot d)$, apologies

Comment: @PrimeMover I've edited the answer with an extended response.

Comment: Thank you extremely -- it's details like this which really are not explained adequately in the literature. I believe it should be. I will ensure my own work is as detailed.